# Using $ instead of jQuery gives error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using following jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery('#main').click(function(){
        jQuery('#box').slideDown();
    }); 
});
```

The above code works fine, however if I use `$` instead of the `jQuery`, I get following error:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
```

I understand that it is because of some conflict, but is there a way that I use `$` in above code?

I have tried to use `jQuery.noConflict();` also but it still gives same error.

Comment: If some other framework has hijacked the $ sign you may need to use a different alias for jquery.

Comment: Do you use any other javascript libraries apart from jQuery ?

Comment: @user1251698 - Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use this:-

```
jQuery(function($) { 
    $('#main').click(function(){
        $('#box').slideDown();
    }); 
});
```

**Aliasing the jQuery Namespace**

When using another JavaScript library, we may wish to call $.noConflict() to avoid namespace difficulties. When this function is called, the $ shortcut is no longer available, forcing us to write jQuery each time we would normally write $. However, the handler passed to the .ready() method can take an argument, which is passed the global jQuery object. This means we can rename the object within the context of our .ready() handler without affecting other code.

<kbd>[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this,

```
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#main').click(function(){
           $('#box').slideDown();
        }); 
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap it in a closure:

```
(function($){

    // use $ as jQuery

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a closure:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#main').click(function () {
            $('#box').slideDown();
        });
    });
})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 1):

First use `noConflict`.

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

then use

```
j(document).ready(function() { 
    j('#main').click(function(){
        j('#box').slideDown();
    }); 
});
```